# git how to set a hook for all the projects

Tags: git

I am reading up on hooks at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy. I usually put wip ( work in progress) as my commit message. I intend to go back and clean it up but sometimes I push changes with message wip. I would like to prevent that.

However rather than putting hook just for one project I would like this wip hook to be in all my projects. Is there a way to setup global hooks.

Answer (score 3):

Look here
[Git commit hooks - global settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293498/git-commit-hooks-global-settings/2293578#2293578), which works thanks to [this](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-init.html#_template_directory)

Answer (score 0):

you can set a global hooks directory with:

```
git config --global core.hooksPath ~/.git-hooks
```