# Locking a branch, so that it cannot be staged/committed into? (Only merged/etc)

Tags: git

I have a `master`/`develop` branching system that i have come to love, but it comes with a basic rule. No commits are done on `develop` or `master`, only merges. This is great, but recently i accidentally made some changes/commits on my develop branch and it annoys the tar out of me.

I looked into moving the ownership of those commits from `develop` into another already existing branch (We'll call it `work`), the one i should have been working on in the first place, but i decided to just let this one go. Instead, i'd like to fix the issue to begin with.. How does one go about locking a branch, so that commit simply doesn't work on it for traditional, normal changes?

Eg, if you made changes on a "locked" branch, you couldn't `git add` nor could you `git commit -a`. I suppose technically i'm asking to lock staging, but you get the idea. Any thoughts on this? Or would i simply be better off learning git well enough that i know how to fix commit parent issues?

Comment: [Git hooks](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html) look like a good start. There's a `pre-commit` hook where you could check things. Not sure how to distinguish between a merge and a normal commit. There's a `post-merge` hook but apparently no `pre-merge`...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Copy this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ `git symbolic-ref HEAD` == "refs/heads/master" ]]
then
    echo "You cannot commit in master!"
    exit 1
fi
```

into a file named `pre-commit` in `.git/hooks/`

It will prevent you from commiting into the branch `master`. You can easily customize it to add more branches or to personalize the error message and so on.

---

BTW, a useful trick to know when you made modifications in `master` but you want to commit them in `somebranch` is to do:

```
git stash
git checkout somebranch
git stash apply
```

and then you are in `somebranch` with your modifications ready to commit!

Comment: Looks great! Anyway this could be added to a global git config? Ie, ~/.git/hooks or something?

Comment: @Lee Olayvar have you made the pre-commit script executable?

Comment: @Lee This question will help you make things global: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293498/git-commit-hooks-global-settings

Comment: Well executable was the problem, but now i seem to be getting the following error.. "/hooks/pre-commit: 7: [[: not found" Thoughts? Pardon my lack of sh knowledge :/

Comment: Maybe `[[ ]]` is bash syntax… Try replacing `#!/bin/sh` by `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Yup, i got that a second ago :D, thanks for the help! Lovely solutions, all around :)

Comment: If you are working of MinGW, it maybe that you don't have `sh` instead of `bash`. If so, change `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/sh`.