# How can I avoid an accidental dcommit from a local branch

Tags: git, git-svn, git-branch, dcommit

Sometimes, I create local branches in git, and I'd like to get a warning message when I try to dcommit from them.

How can I prevent myself from accidentally dcommiting from a local branch?

Comment: Not built-in but an idea: As soon as you branch, do a `git config --rename-section "svn-remote.svn" "no-svn-remote"`. Once you want to do the dcommit, you can revert that.

Comment: Or maybe I could specify somehow that there is no upstream branch for this local branch? Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: I researched that in the light of your question, but it looks like that git svn doesn't get the local branch switch, so it thinks it's still on the trunk or the checkout out branch/tag. It could be worth a try to change the default branches line in the config file to test this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative to pre-commit hooks, if you're using Linux (or Git bash or Cygwin or similar), is to wrap `git` in a shell helper function.  Add the below to your `~/.bashrc` (for bash, Git bash) or `~/.zshrc` (for zsh) file, or whatever the equivalent is for your shell:

```
real_git=$(which git)
function git {
    if [[ ($1 == svn) && ($2 == dcommit) ]]
    then
        curr_branch=$($real_git branch | sed -n 's/\* //p')
        if [[ ($curr_branch != master) && ($curr_branch != '(no branch)') ]]
        then
            echo "Committing from $curr_branch; are you sure? [y/N]"
            read resp
            if [[ ($resp != y) && ($resp != Y) ]]
            then
                return 2
            fi
        fi
    fi
    $real_git "$@"
}
```

(I've tested this with bash and zsh on Red Hat, and bash on Cygwin)

Whenever you call `git`, you'll now be calling this function rather than the normal binary. The function will run git normally, unless you're calling `git svn dcommit` while attached to a branch that's not master. In that case, it'll prompt you to confirm before doing the commit. You can override the function by specifying the path to `git` explicitly (that's what the `$real_git` is doing).

Remember that after updating `~/.bashrc` or equivalent, you'll need to reload it, either by starting a new shell session (logging out and logging in again) or by running `source ~/.bashrc`.

**Edit**: As an enhancement, you can remove the first line, starting `real_git=`, and replace the other instances of `$real_git` with `command git`, which achieves the same thing but in the preferred way. I've not updated the script itself as I've not been able to test the change on zsh.

Comment: Incidentally, if you want to test how this works, `git svn dcommit --dry-run` will trigger the same checking behaviour as `git svn dcommit`, without actually trying to perform the commit itself.

Comment: I'm using linux + zsh, your solution shouldn't be too hard for me to adapt, I try that when I can.

Comment: I've just tested the above in zsh; it works fine for me. Just put the code into `~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 2):

First thing that comes in mind is using a git pre-commit hook to solve the problem. This would be easy for pure git repos:

- Lock remote branches (update hook): [Is there a way to lock a branch in GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471340/is-there-a-way-to-lock-a-branch-in-git)
- Lock local branches (pre-commit hook): [Locking a branch, so that it cannot be staged/committed into? (Only merged/etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073258/locking-a-branch-so-that-it-cannot-be-staged-commited-into-only-merged-etc)

But as discussed in [Hooks for git-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014422/hooks-for-git-svn), this isn't fully working. [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) came up with an (accepted) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2032889/520162) where he utilizes an intermediate bare repo that acts like kind of a proxy between git ans SVN.

Maybe this could help you too.

Comment: The second link looks promising. +1

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else needs this for Windows Powershell:

```
    function CallGit
    { 
        if (($args[0] -eq "svn") -And ($args[1] -eq "dcommit")) {
            $curr_branch = &{git branch};
            $curr_branch = [regex]::Match($curr_branch, '\* (\w*)').captures.groups[1].value
            if ($curr_branch -ne "master") {
                Write-Warning "Committing from branch $curr_branch";
                $choice = ""
                while ($choice -notmatch "[y|n]"){
                    $choice = read-host "Do you want to continue? (Y/N)"
                }
                if ($choice -ne "y"){
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        &"git.exe" @args
    }
    Set-Alias -Name git -Value CallGit -Description "Avoid an accidental git svn dcommit on a local branch"
```