# Git pre-svn-dcommit hook

Tags: git, git-svn, githooks

I work on a remote SVN repository using `git-svn` and I use [`git-flow`](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) workflow for my local development.

Unfortunately accidentally a couple of times I did the `svn dcommit` while being on a feature branch, while I want to only `dcommit` master.

What I'd like to do is to create a `pre-svn-dcommit` hook that would check whether I'm on the master branch or not. Unfortunately git doesn't seem to ship with such hook.

I did find two potential approaches/solution:

1. https://github.com/padwan-ragavan/preSVNDcommitHook - I'm not too comfortable with replacing the git-svn binary though.
2. http://davidsouther.com/2012/04/git-svn-dcommit-hooks/ - this on the other hand looks a bit too complicated for my liking (and needs).

Any advices how this can be achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I avoid an accidental dcommit from a local branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226528/how-can-i-avoid-an-accidental-dcommit-from-a-local-branch)

Comment: This thread says that this functionality was added.. but it doesn't seem to run my pre commit hook when I try it: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-git-svn-hook-before-git-svn-dcommit-td6540838.html

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Git alias that throws an error when you're trying to commit on a non-master branch:

```
svndcm = "!f(){ if [[ $(git branch --no-color | sed -n "s/\* \(.*\)/\1/p") == "master" ]]; then git svn dcommit; else echo "Error"; fi }; f"
```

Include the above line in the `[alias]` section of your `~/.gitconfig` file and then use `git svndcm` to dcommit your changes. Modify the alias name and error message to your liking :)

Answer (score 1):

As you note, there's no easy solution using Git natively. I achieve similar things by using the shell to catch calls to `git` and add additional features before calling `git` itself.

See [How can I avoid an accidental dcommit from a local branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226528/how-can-i-avoid-an-accidental-dcommit-from-a-local-branch/9330342#9330342) for a script that should do exactly what you're after.