# Does running git init twice initialize a repository or reinitialize an existing repo?

Tags: git

What happens to an existing git repository when you issue `git init` again?

I created a repository with `git init`.  Created a file, add, commit. Check the status (nothing to commit). Then created another file, check the status and I can see it's untracked as expected.

Then, say by mistake, I run `git init` again and I get *Reinitialise existing Git repository message*.

Tried `git status`, but it shows the same. So what really happens?

Can reinitialising an existing git repository this way be harmful or helpful? Why can we `git init` inside an existing repository?

Comment: FWIW using Xcode I first created the **local** repository for the *first* time, then when I went to Github.com to create a new remote repository. Which I did, then to link my local repository to my remote...I was following its steps (provided on Github.com), its first step is `git init` which I did. Presumably it was the 2nd time *after* Xcode automatically had created it

Answer (score 252, accepted):

From the git [docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html):

> Running git init in an existing repository is safe. It will not overwrite things that are already there. The primary reason for rerunning git init is to pick up newly added templates.

Answer (score 120):

This is described in the [`git init`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) documentation:

> Running *git init* in an existing repository is safe. It will not overwrite things that are already there. The primary reason for rerunning *git init* is to pick up newly added templates.

Answer (score 54):

Since v1.7.5 ([b57fb80a7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b57fb80a7d7d19102b31ab94a28ed43ea1ee07bb)), `git init` in an existing repo has also allowed moving the `.git` directory:

> The primary reason for
>   rerunning 'git init' is to pick up newly added templates (or to move
>   the repository to another place if --separate-git-dir is given).

'Picking up newly-added templates' means that any templates which have not already been copied from [the template directory](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init/2.2.1#_template_directory) will now be copied into the existing git directory.

'Moving the repository to another place' means that, if `--separate-git-dir` points to somewhere else, the existing `.git` directory will be moved there and replaced by a link.

Comment: I didn't understand "pick up newly added templates" part. Could you tell me what this mean?