# How to pull remote branch from somebody else's repo

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-pull, git-remote

I've got a project hosted on GitHub which somebody has forked. On their fork, they've created a new branch "foo" and made some changes.  How do I pull their "foo" into a new branch also named "foo" in my repo?

I understand they could submit a pull request to me, but I'd like to initiate this process myself.

Assume the following:

1. Because they forked my project, both our repos share the same 'history'
2. Although GitHub shows their project was forked from mine, my local repository doesn't have any references to this person's project. Do I need to add theirs as a remote?
3. I don't have a branch called "foo" yet - I don't know if I need to manually create this first.
4. I definitely want this pulled into a separate branch and not my master.

Answer (score 553, accepted):

```
git remote add coworker git://path/to/coworkers/repo.git
git fetch coworker
git checkout --track coworker/foo
```

This will setup a local branch `foo`, tracking the remote branch `coworker/foo`. So when your co-worker has made some changes, you can easily pull them:

```
git checkout foo
git pull
```

---

Response to comments:

> Cool :) And if I'd like to make my own
>   changes to that branch, should I
>   create a second local branch "bar"
>   from "foo" and work there instead of
>   directly on my "foo"?

You don't need to create a new branch, even though I recommend it. You might as well commit directly to `foo` and have your co-worker pull your branch. But that branch already exists and your branch `foo` need to be setup as an upstream branch to it:

```
git branch --set-upstream foo colin/foo
```

assuming `colin` is your repository (a remote to your co-workers repository) defined in similar way:

```
git remote add colin git://path/to/colins/repo.git
```

Comment: That was very fast :)  You might want to add that he should use the `git://` URL from the other person's GitHub repository page in the place of `//path/to/coworkers/repo.git`.  (Describing that was what made my answer too slow ;))

Comment: Cool :) And if I'd like to make my own changes to that branch, should I create a second local branch "bar" from "foo" and work there instead of directly on my "foo"?

Comment: Or is it safe to work directly in my "foo" and pull/merge his changes in later? Which is the best practice here?

Comment: Nice answer in 3 minutes!

Comment: with git version 2.19.1.windows.1 I needed to replace `git checkout --track coworker/foo` with just `git checkout foo`

Answer (score 200):

The accepted answer works, but you **don't need to add them as a remote**, since that would be cumbersome and a pain to do each time.

#### Grabbing their commits:

```bash
git fetch git://path/to/coworkers/repo.git theirbranch:ournameforbranch
```

This creates a local branch named `ournameforbranch` which is exactly the same as what `theirbranch` was for them.  For the question example, the last argument would be `foo:foo`.

The `git://path/to/coworkers/repo.git` part should be replaced with the URL on their GitHub repository page.  An SSH URL would look like `git@github.com:theirusername/reponame.git` and an HTTPS one like `https://github.com/theirusername/reponame.git`.

Note `:ournameforbranch` part can be further left off if thinking up a name that doesn't conflict with one of your own branches is bothersome. In that case, a reference called `FETCH_HEAD` is available.  You can `git log FETCH_HEAD` to see their commits then do things like `cherry-picked` to cherry pick their commits.

#### Pushing it back to them:

Oftentimes, you want to *fix* something of theirs and push it right back.  That's possible too:

```
git fetch git://path/to/coworkers/repo.git theirbranch
git checkout FETCH_HEAD

# fix fix fix

git push git://path/to/coworkers/repo.git HEAD:theirbranch
```

If working in [*detached state*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head) worries you, by all means create a branch using `:ournameforbranch` and replace `FETCH_HEAD` and `HEAD` above with `ournameforbranch`.

Comment: Thank you for this, the other answer does not work if both you and the other person have identically named branches (like the default `master` branch)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this method won't work if you don't have stuff like SSH key associated with your github account, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626

Comment: don't you have to be added as a collaborator so you could push to their repo?

Comment: @Honey Certainly!  Pushing assumes you have the necessary permissions on the remote end to push.  Fetching likewise assumes the path is accessible.

Comment: If you run `git branch -m newbranch` while in this detached state, git will lose its mind and start saying your repo isn't valid anymore. `git init` seems to fix it and put you back in more or less the state you were in before, with the branch named "newbranch".

Comment: *saying your repo isn't valid anymore*: @IanHickson No, it's telling you you aren't on a branch in its own cryptic way.  It's `git branch -m <newname> [<oldname>]` to rename a branch.  Since you omitted `<oldname>` you need to be on a branch for git to know what you want to rename.  Not sure how `git init` managed to do the things you said as it [does practically nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149694/does-running-git-init-twice-initialize-a-repository-or-reinitialize-an-existing).  Maybe you were after `git checkout [-b] newbranch`.

Comment: @antak I can't repro on my linux box. The issue I ran into was on a Mac, so maybe macOS has some old version of git installed with some forgotten bugs. In any case, the error message I saw was not just that I wasn't on a branch, it was "fatal: Not a git repository". Running `git init` fixed it.

Comment: I couldn't do the "Grabbing their commits" because I'm an utter newbie and got these errors: `The authenticity of host 'github.com (20.205.243.166)' can't be established.` and after agreeing to continue `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).`
`fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Comment: @hippietrail I see where my answer went wrong.  I've updated the answer to clarify the URL part. My previous wording directed you to use an SSH url but an HTTPS one will work in its place.  You can also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12940681/1036728) for further clarification on the two types of authentication.

Comment: @antak Thanks! I did find that answer after I'd already commented. Hopefully the whole thread will be easier for people who find it in the future.

Answer (score 36):

The following is a nice expedient solution that works with GitHub for checking out the PR branch from another user's fork. You need to know the pull request ID (which GitHub displays along with the PR title).

*Example:*

**Pull request** #8
**alice** wants to merge 1 commit into `your_repo:master` from `her_repo:branch`

```
git checkout -b <branch>
git pull origin pull/8/head
```

- Substitute `<branch>` with the branch name from `her_repo:branch`
- Substitute the name of your remote if you called it something different from `origin`.
- Substitute `8` with the correct pull request ID.

Comment: This Needs more upvotes. works pe3rfectly and avoided the "fatal: Couldn't find remote ref" error I was getting with the top-voted answer. Thanks!

Comment: 2 lines of easy code.  Thanks for sharing this!  The only thing sweeter than this is merging out updates back into their pull request in a easy fashion.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: This answer is not clear

Answer (score 23):

If antak's answer:

```
git fetch git@github.com:<THEIR USERNAME>/<REPO>.git <THEIR BRANCH>:<OUR NAME FOR BRANCH>
```

gives you:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Then (following Przemek D's advice) use

```
git fetch https://github.com/<THEIR USERNAME>/<REPO>.git <THEIR BRANCH>:<OUR NAME FOR BRANCH>
```

Answer (score 7):

If the forked repo is protected so you can't push directly into it, and your goal is to make changes to their foo, then you need to get their branch foo into your repo like so:

```
git remote add protected_repo https://github.com/theirusername/their_repo.git
git fetch protected_repo 
git checkout --no-track protected_repo/foo
```

Now you have a local copy of foo with no upstream associated to it. You can commit changes to it (or not) and then push your foo to your own remote repo.

```
git push --set-upstream origin foo
```

Now foo is in your repo on GitHub and your local foo is tracking it. If they continue to make changes to foo you can fetch theirs and merge into your foo.

```
git checkout foo 
git fetch protected_repo
git merge protected_repo/foo
```

Answer (score 7):

Update: this no longer seems to work, as Github changed their UI, let's hope they'll restore it

---

GitHub has a new option relative to the preceding answers, just copy/paste the command lines from the PR:

1. Scroll to the bottom of the PR to see the `Merge` or `Squash and merge` button
2. Click the link on the right: `view command line instructions`
3. Press the Copy icon to the right of Step 1
4. Paste the commands in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this while trying to continue a Azure DevOps Repos PR a collegue had created earlier.
Approach I ended up using:

```
<navigate to relevant directory aka. git repo on local machine>

git fetch --all
# Optional verification: git branch -a

git checkout -b <local-branch> <remote-branch>
# e.g: git checkout -b 007_Bondbranch remotes/origin/007_Bondbranch

# Optional verification: git remotes -v

# Continue normally via git add, git commit and git push
```

Answer (score -1):

git fetch upstream pull/<pr_number>/head:<your_local_branch_name>