# Update the fork Github

Tags: git, github

I have forked a remote repo and it has 3 branches

1. master
2. a
3. b

But the team added new branches to the remote.
And the current branches are

1. master
2. a
3. b
4. c
5. d
6. e

but my fork has only 3 branches. How should I update my fork to contain all the branches (including newly added branches) present in remote repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the original repo as a second remote to your local repo:

```
git remote add parentrepo <url>
```

Fetch all branches from it:

```
git fetch parentrepo
```

Given what you have said, `git branch -a` should give (assuming you have `origin` as the alias for your fork as it is by default when you clone)

```
* master
origin/master
origin/a
origin/b
parentrepo/a
parentrepo/b
parentrepo/c
parentrepo/d
parentrepo/e
```

You can branch any remote branch from parentrepo locally as you would for origin, and/or push them directly to origin.

Comment: Can we do this from web interface of github at this point of time ?

Answer (score 2):

Now, there are two steps involved. Fetching newly added branches from remote repository and pushing those branches to your fork.

To fetch, newly added branches from remote repository say original, do

```
1. git remote add original {url_to_remote}
2. git fetch original
```

See this [Pull branches from remote repository SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884784/how-to-pull-remote-branch-from-somebody-elses-repo)

Now, we have pulled remote branches on our local repo. Next we want to send these branches to our fork.

```
1. git push -u origin {branch_name} // Origin is your fork
```

Comment: You edited the OP's question, changing the meaning. I doubt his question is how to push branches, he's asking how to push recently added branches from a parent project back into his own fork's remote.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian..Kind enough to tell me. I have updated the question once again. Does it make sense now ?

Comment: hai @blunderboy am edited the question with the correct meaning

Answer (score 1):

Just to cover yourself when the team removes remote branches and you don't have their updates, I would do 2 commands:

```
git remote prune origin
```

and

```
git fetch origin
```