# How to start working off a remote branch, Github

Tags: git, github, git-clone, remote-branch

I am new to Github and i have a question that i have been trying to find an answer. 
Say i have three repositories, Origin, Repo1 (my repo - forked from Origin), Repo2 (my colleague's repo forked from Origin).
We work on our own repos, and then make pull requests to origin.

How can I clone my colleague's repo2/branch1 into my local repo? If i use git pull, it merges my local branch into repo2/branch1. What i want is to create a new branch in my local repo which contains exactly and only what is in repo2/branch1. Is there a command to do that ?

What i have to do now everytime i want to do something similar is "CLONE" the whole repo2 which is time consuming and problematic.

Thanks very much.

**UPDATE ANSWER**

```
git fetch repo2
git checkout -b repo2_branch1 repo2/branch1
```

will remote track branch1 of repo2 on my local machine as a branch called repo2_branch1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull remote branch from somebody else's repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884784/how-to-pull-remote-branch-from-somebody-elses-repo)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new branch in your repo  (Repo1).

```
git checkout -b trackRepo2
```

This will start will your code base, and you'll have to merge the changes made by your friend to it. Proceed as follows.

Add your friends repo as a remote for this new branch

```
git remote add git_Repo2 <address of Repo2>
```

Now, simply do a pull (or a fetch and merge) from your friend's repo, using the following command.

```
git pull git_Repo2 master
```

Assuming it's master branch of Repo2 that you are interested in.
You can also set the branch `master` at `Repo2` as your default upstream branch for your local branch `trackRepo2`, then you'll just have to do `git pull` , without mentioning `git_Repo2 master` every time.