# How to get newly added branches from upstream into origin?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, devops

Suppose, I've repo - https://server/tests/ui and when I forked it, it has two branches - `master` and `release`.

Suppose after few days, someone adds new branch say `feature` to upstream. If I want to take that new branch into my fork, which git commands should I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fetch an unmerged pull request for a branch I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743514/how-can-i-fetch-an-unmerged-pull-request-for-a-branch-i-dont-own)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull remote branch from somebody else's repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884784/how-to-pull-remote-branch-from-somebody-elses-repo)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+how+to+pull+a+new+branch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+how+to+fetch+a+new+branch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

Answer (score 4):

Best way to do it would be to first fetch the new branch from upstream into your cloned local repo and then push it to origin.

Below are the git commands:

```
git fetch upstream
```

Above command will fetch the new upstream branch.

```
git checkout -b feature upstream/feature
```

This will create a local branch with the name feature.

```
git push -u origin feature
```

This will push the new branch to the origin and will start tracking it(keeping the branch name same on origin).

Hope this helps you!!

Answer (score 1):

you do a `git fetch` then

if you have only one remote let's say origin you do

```
git checkout feature
```

if you have multiple remotes

```
git checkout -b feature remote_name/feature
```