# Git reinitalising, when I want a new pull

Tags: git, github, initialization, pull, git-pull

How do I get a new pull? Each time I am trying to do it, it is pulling on the same git I had before, but I am trying to pull a new. How do I do that?

I am not trying to do what you would normally do, which is update an existing one, as described here: 
[Does running git init twice initialize a repository or reinitialize an existing repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149694/does-running-git-init-twice-initialize-a-repository-or-reinitialize-an-existing)

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to clone a new copy of a repository to a different directory entirely? If so, cd to a parent directory and run `git clone [clone-url] [directory-name]` (e.g. `git clone https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git bootstrap-new-directory/`).

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from the question, but my guess is that you are trying to pull from a different repository then you originally pulled, but into the same local repository.

To do this, use `git remote add <name> <url>` to add the new repository as an additional remote, and pull from the new remote with `git pull <name>`

Checkout the [git remote](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) man page for more information.