# git init command, when reinitializing, what are the new templates?

Tags: git

for the answer to the post here: [Does running git init twice initialize a repository or reinitialize an existing repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149694/does-running-git-init-twice-initialize-a-repository-or-reinitialize-an-existing/5149857#5149857)
, i understand it is safe and glad that it is so, but can you please explain what these new templates are? do they matter and will they just be additions rather than changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template directory (by default, `/usr/share/git-core/templates`) contains files and directories that will be copied to the `$GIT_DIR` (by default `.git`) after it is created. 
It's usually used to share hooks, commit message templates, etc. between all the git projects on the same machine.

The so-called "problem" (read: defined behavior), is that the content of this directory is **copied** to each project instead of been a symbolic link. So if you update the contents of the template directory (e.g., add another hook), you'd have to `git init` your project again to copy it to that project.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider to check this problem similar with `git init` command [Reinitialized existing Git repository in c:/xampp/htdocs/website/.git/](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25867686/3763032) T__T #HELP

**EDIT**: However, this problem similar to mine, I've got "index" corruption as well. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1115956/3763032) saved me a lot of time.