# Reinitialized existing Git repository in c:/xampp/htdocs/website/.git/

Tags: git, repository, init

I already made a project there, add, commit, push. Unfotunately, I've got power surgery :'(

When I've tried restart my PC, I `cd` back to my project folder, but suddenly it looks like these:

`UserName@PC /c/xampp/htdocs/website`

before
`UserName@PC /c/xampp/htdocs/website (master)`

I tried `git init` and this showed up:

`Reinitialized existing Git repository in c:/xampp/htdocs/website/.git/`

but, nothing happen to my repo T__T

it still looks like these:
`UserName@PC /c/xampp/htdocs/website`

Thank you very much, your guidance please t(^_^)

**EDIT**: I did `git stash save` before power surgery & this files comes up:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOB4F.jpg

Comment: Sometimes it is in hidden mode, so try to hide a folder once and unhide the folder again now you'll find the .git directory in the respected folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did push, you can try and:

- clone again in another folder
- check that it does look like /c/xampp/htdocs/otherfolder (master)
- if it does, rename otherfolder to website, and go on working in that fresh clone

Comment: recently, I found that my `.git/index` & `.git/HEAD` file is corrupted after power surgery :'( Thank you for your advice sir, I though I would do a `git clone` but I didn't do much push either before >_< I stash every last my changed files and **bam**, I didn't remember the last time I did either `git commit` nor `git push`

Comment: @MochaD yes, small andfrequents commits are best practice, and would ensure that you don't find yourself in this pickle in the future.

Comment: yeah sir, I made much commit and try to minimize my doing. And try `git stash` to compare other branch much quicker, without have to `commit` first, or even twice `commit` with a tiny little changes ;'( I should try to search about this corruption, maybe I can find some solution! @VonC thank you very much sir!

Comment: yet, I can't voted up your answer, I just had this account a month ago :D and still had 12 reputation, because you voted up mine question :D

Answer (score 1):

Use `rd .git /S/Q` before running the `git init` command.