# git status shows Index corrupted, after git stash

Tags: git, indexing, corrupt, git-stash

I already made my [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25867686/3763032), but I still don't know is there any ways to recover back my `.git/index & .git/HEAD`

I had corrupted .git/index & .git/HEAD, take a look at this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DskN3.jpg).

Please, if you had experience this problem too, or any other solution to provides :) I'm just newbie for a git t(^_^)

Thank you for taking time, to see what's going on :)

Answer (score 0):

Though, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1115956/3763032) answered my problem, to do a little `git reset --keep`! If you guys had a same problem, don't panicked out yet. Do a small frequently `commit` or `stash` before you go to another rampage.