# What does 'reinitialize' mean/actually do in git?

Tags: git, git-init

I found a related question below, but can't understand 'pick up newly added templates', and seems this explaination was removed in latest http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init

[Does running git init twice initialize a repository or reinitialize an existing repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149694/does-running-git-init-twice-initialize-a-repository-or-reinitialize-an-existing)

> Running git init in an existing repository is safe. It will not
>   overwrite things that are already there. The primary reason for
>   rerunning git init is to pick up newly added templates.

I just don't know what will reinitialize actually do, hope someone can explain it detail, thanks a lot :)

Comment: The "marked as duplicate" text says "If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question." This question is exactly that: The OP read the duplicate, didn't understand part of the answer, and asked a new question (this one). I'm nominating this for reopening.

Answer (score 2):

The same [`git init` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) has this to say about templates:

> ### Template directory
>
> The template directory contains files and directories that will be copied to the `$GIT_DIR` after it is created.
>
> The template directory will be one of the following (in order):
>
> - the argument given with the `--template` option;
> - the contents of the `$GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR` environment variable;
> - the `init.templatedir` configuration variable; or
> - the default template directory: `/usr/share/git-core/templates.`
>
> The default template directory includes some directory structure, suggested "exclude patterns" (see [gitignore[5]](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)), and sample hook files (see [githooks[5]](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)).

So if you have manually changed the files in `/usr/share/git-core/templates`, or possibly upgraded to a new version of Git that came with different templates, reinitializing will copy those new files into an existing repository.

The documentation also suggests another reason for reinitializing:

> to move the repository to another place if `--separate-git-dir` is given

And later:

> `--separate-git-dir=<git dir>`
>
> Instead of initializing the repository as a directory to either `$GIT_DIR` or `./.git/`, create a text file there containing the path to the actual repository. This file acts as filesystem-agnostic Git symbolic link to the repository.
>
> If this is reinitialization, the repository will be moved to the specified path.