# "Not a git repository" after OS reset

Tags: windows, git

This morning my Windows 10 crashed and rebooted once I lifted my laptop's screen. No special activity was progressing, so I don't think there was significant disk activity.

However one of my main Git repos crashed after that reset. Here is what I tried:

- `$ git status`
  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
- `$ git init`
  Reinitialized existing Git repository in ....../.git/
- `$ git status`
  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
- Loop

I don't think I have unpushed commits, so wiping and cloning from remote should work.

Still, can I ask what to do to recover an existing Git repository (`.git` directory still exists, `chkdsk` reports OK) in such cases?

[Add] read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149694/does-running-git-init-twice-initialize-a-repository-or-reinitialize-an-existing) but did not apply to my case (I can't restore the repo)

Comment: First copy .git to somewhere else immediately. The entire repo even. Next re-install git, see if that works and use backup if necessary.

Comment: Can you expand on "use backup"? Should I re-clone the repository and overwrite the .git folder from the backup? Upvoted for the word "immediately"

Comment: You should always keep copies of your repos. With git it's as easy as `git push`. You should have made a copy of the entire folder before trying `git init` or any other command to avoid causing additional damage. Copy the folder anyway, just in case your working files are OK.

Comment: probably what you might be interested in is this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129214/how-to-backup-a-local-git-repository

Comment: I'm hoping after re-install your repo will work (`git status`), but if it doesn't and you delete the `.git` folder and init again, then just copy the backup `.git` over.

Comment: btw from a small quick answer, every clone is a backup of the repo itself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578270/fully-backup-a-git-repo

Comment: @kabanus what a great advice! I think **that** is the answer. I can see I restored all (?) my checked out branches. Git fsck reported an error indeed in a single branch where I had no work unpushed. Once I think I am done with that I could expand into a community answer

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As [kabanus said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907497/not-a-git-repository-after-os-reset#comment69027497_40907497), you should definitely save whatever you can before proceeding (and/or use some other existing clone as a backup).

When Git complains about this, though, it often means that the file `.git/HEAD` has gone missing.  If you create a new `HEAD` file with contents: `ref: refs/heads/master`, Git may be able to recover everything.

Since `HEAD` is the most active file in the repository, it's the one most likely to be clobbered by an OS error or power failure.  It's also a critical file when it comes to whether Git believes a `.git` directory is a repository: if the directory contains a file named `HEAD` (along with a few other key items), it *is* a repository; if not, it is *not* a repository.

Comment: Endorsed.  I had power-failure mid-way through branching in SmartGit on MS Windows 10.  After restart, couldn't open the repo. Editing the HEAD fle just worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Same here - computer froze, HEAD was full of nulls - as was `REBASE_HEAD` and a couple other files inside the rebase-merge folder. Was even able to complete the rebase, using the non corrupted reflog after the repository was recognised again.

Comment: In my case machine was accidently shutdown during a git process. And HEAD file was changed into `0000 0000...`. So, putting `ref: refs/heads/master` in `.git/HEAD` and `git reset --hard` then `git fetch --all` solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had multiple branches corrupt due to OS error (bloody windows sleep function!!). So I had to manually do the following:

1. **.git/HEAD** (set content to `ref: refs/heads/master`)
2. `$> git branch -v` (this will tell you all the corrupt branches)
3. **.git/logs/HEAD** (Read the file for last checksum of the commits and merge of corrupt branches)
4. **.git/refs/heads/{corrupt branch file}** (change the checksum to the last working checksum from the log file.
5. merge the branches again as per need.

Comment: also, after step 3, do a `branch -v` to confirm if its fixed

Comment: I tried it but no success, just deleted all the files and cloned the repository again (¬_¬ )

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the `HEAD` file was indeed corrupted due to a system crash.

I just cloned the repo again into a new folder, switched to the branch I was in, then replaced the `.git` folder with the one I just created from the clone.

From there, it was like nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround for this, Solved for me while OS crashed on GIT MERGE operation

1. Get the working HEAD,FETCH_HEAD files under .git/ directory(of your project) from some other contributor
2. Replace the existing HEAD,FETCH_HEAD files with new ones(taken from other contributor).
3. Delete the INDEX under .git/ directory.
4. Then Do a git pull.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, The ownership of the repo was mismatched after OS reset.
I tried @raheel-hasan's instructions, after entering `git branch -v` command I got a suggestion.

[image]

`git config --global --add safe.directory 'direactory path'` this command solved the issue :)

(Use powershell to run this command)

You shoult reload your IDE or code editor after running this command.