# How to reinit local git repo with existing .git - repository

Tags: git

I have a problem with my local git repository. My OS failed to work with git bash and automatically restarted my computer, and when I restarted git bash in my project and tried to interact, git bash return error
**fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git**
But why? My *.git* repository is still in my project, but any repository actions are unavailable. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/40907497/1256452

Comment: @torek thanks, it's worked for me