# Undo git init on git project that already contained .git folder (recover previous commits)

Tags: git, github

I had a project that I `git init`ed earlier and pushed commits to origin remote. I've made some changes to the code and was ready to make a second commit, but accidentally sent `git init` instead of `git status`. Is there a way to undo it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does running git init twice initialize a repository or reinitialize an existing repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149694/does-running-git-init-twice-initialize-a-repository-or-reinitialize-an-existing)

Comment: @funnydman Yes, thanks