# Git: is it possible to edit the commit message using the pre-push hook?

Tags: git

Before users push their commits, I'd like to pre-pend the branch name to the commit message.  Is this possible?

If it is, would I use the `git commit --amend` command?

Our branch names contain the ticket number and its important to see this info when its merged into master and in Jenkins.  To see it easily, it must be the first line in the commit message.  To ensure the fist line is the branch name (containing the ticket number), I'd like to use the pre-push hook.  I could use other hooks, such as `prepare-commit-message` or use a message template but that puts the branch name on every commit, and it doesn't ensure that the branch name is there after a rebase.   Using the pre-push ensures the branch name is there before it goes into the remote.

=============

#### update:  Yes, it is possible but its a bad idea.

The pre-push hook syncs the refs with the remote **before** running but before any objects are pushed.  This means the remote already has the commit sha set for the change you are pushing.  When the `pre-push` hook ammends the commit message a new sha is generated, putting you immediately out of sync with the remote.

Comment: I'm certain this is possible, but why would you want to do this?  Branches are ephemeral in nature; the scope of work - being the ticket number - would be what you'd want to capture.

Comment: You got it.  I want to ensure the ticket number is in the commit message.  Since our branches are generated from within Jira, they contain the ticket number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jira issue number in git commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365554/jira-issue-number-in-git-commit-message)

Comment: It's possible. But a commit can "belong" to infinitive number of branches that are existing or to be created or deleted in the future. If you write the branch name in the commit message, it would be misleading. The `prepare-commit-msg` hook may be a better place to do the job.

Comment: I'm specifically looking to use the pre-push hook.  There are other hooks to aid in formatting messages but its the pre-push that suites my needs best.  My goal is to not interfere with the users commit messages until necessary, which means just before they push to the remote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've found, the answer is effectively "no".  In fact it's *truly* "no", for a deeper technical reason: it's impossible to edit *any* commit.  What `git commit --amend` does is not "edit a commit", but rather, shove the commit aside and change the current branch name, whatever that is, to point to the new commit.  The "before" picture is:

```
...--o--o--*   <--current_branch (HEAD)
```

and the "after" one is:

```
          *   [abandoned - in reflog as HEAD@{1}, etc]
         /
...--o--o--X   <--current_branch (HEAD)
```

But the pre-push hook runs after your Git has already called up the other Git and offered to send it commit `*` by its hash ID.  The fact that you've *replaced* commit `*` by new-and-improved commit `X` is now irrelevant: your Git is dedicated to pushing commit `*` and asking their Git to set *their* branch to point to (their copy of) commit `*`.

What you can do, in this pre-push hook, is *reject* the push from your own end.  Now that the push is rejected and fails, you can re-run your `git push` command.  This time you'll propose to send them commit `X`.  If it looks right, you won't have any need to run `git commit --amend` and can leave commit `X` in place for the push, and let the push run.

Note that it's far better to do this *outside* Git.  Instead of:

```
$ git push remotename HEAD:somebranch
```

or whatever it is you actually run, you would just run:

```
$ jirapush
```

which is your own script.  In this script, you can run whatever Git commands you like, in whatever order, *before* running `git push remotename <hash>:<branchname>` or whatever it is that you will run at the very end.  Those Git commands can include, e.g.:

```
generate_new_commit_message_text | git commit --amend -F -
```

if necessary.  Since it all happens *before* `git push` fires up, it's well in time to do whatever it is you want done.