# How to stage line by line in git gui although "No newline at end of file" warning

Tags: git, newline, git-gui, git-index, line-by-line

I use *git gui* to select lines for being staged for a commit. This normally works like a charm. I am aware of the option to do the same on the command line.

Whenever a file does not initially have a new line at the end of the file *git gui* recognizes this and appends a warning message in the editor as I illustrated in the screenshot.

[image: Git Gui]

### Problem

The problem which results from the missing line break is that one **can no longer stage and commit individual lines**. When I right-click to select the specific line and choose <kbd>Stage line for commit</kbd> from the context menu an error message pops up.

> error: fatal: corrupt parch at line 11.

The problem is not specific to the operating system and can be repoduced on Windows, MacOSX and Linux. I know that I can avoid the problem if I add a new line to the file and commit this version before I continue selecting individual lines.

### Steps to reproduce the problem

1. Initialize a new repository.
2. Create a file with three lines of content each with the word "Hallo". Do not put a new line at the end of the file.
3. Add and commit the file.
4. Edit the same file putting words inbetween the three lines.
5. Open *git gui* and try to stage the changes line by line.

### Request

I wonder if there is some configuration for Git which allows me to circumvent the problem. Some automatism such as a hook which adds the desired new line would also be fine.

### Bug report

I sent a bug report to the Git mailing list. You can follow and participate in the discussion [here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-gui-Warning-quot-No-newline-at-end-of-file-td7571185.html).

Comment: This is really a bug report for git-gui. This problem should only occur for the last hunk in a file. What is happening is when you stage lines, git-gui constructs a patch and then applies it via 'git apply'. In this case we need to remove the last line and re-add it with a newline and leave the "\ No newline at end of file" marker as context. This all happens in lib/diff.tcl apply_range_or_line. It's not trivial but should be fixable.

Comment: I agree: it would be nice if this could be fixed in *git gui*. Though, I do not know if other UI tools fight the same problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [Heiko Voigt](http://github.com/hvoigt) there is a bugfix for the behavior. We fixed this at the [Git-Merge conference](http://git-merge.com) - thanks to GitHub for organizing this. The patch is pending on the mailing list at the moment. As soon as it is merged and released I am going the update this post here.

- http://www.mail-archive.com/git@vger.kernel.org/msg25556.html
- http://github.com/hvoigt/git/tree/hv/git-gui-fix-no-newline

---

Finally, [gitgui-0.18.0](https://github.com/git/git/tree/gitgui-0.18.0) has been merged into [git v1.8.4](https://github.com/git/git/tree/v1.8.4) and is part of the official release (Aug 23, 2013). Now everybody can enjoy staging linewise commits regardless of a new line at the end of the file. Thanks again to Heiko!

Comment: @Ikraav I think you are the first person I noticed who is actually concerned about this bug. Nevertheless, I am looking forward to the bugfix release.

Comment: We are currently doing a bit (admittedly over-)centralized git stuff, running git gui remotely for various users to commit their work. This bug has bitten us annoyingly in the butt for a while. Today's been a good day, that's all I got to say about this :)

Comment: @Ikraav I am glad I made your day a nice one :)

Answer (score 3):

I found an **pre-commit hook** which takes care of the problem. Though, it is not the perfect solution since the fix applies not until you actually *commit* the file. I created a gist for the script so you can modify it if you like to improve on it.

- [pre-commit hook](https://gist.github.com/4024222)

The [original script was posted by Matt Baker](http://eng.wealthfront.com/2011/03/corrective-action-with-gits-pre-commit.html). I reduced it to the fact of **adding a new line** but also included the routines for **removing trailing whitespace**. There is however one change regards the linebreak character: I added `\n` contrary to Matt's recommendation.

**Problem case:**

I used the script in a *git rebase* workflow. This caused git to change all files which have trailing spaces. It resulted in a massive diff. Therefore, I recommend to think over using the script.

---

Furthermore, I found this discussion on how to [integrate hooks into multiple repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293498/git-commit-hooks-global-settings) quite interesting. You might wanna look into this when setting up your own hooks.