# How do I prevent Git from auto-detecting user.email?

Tags: git, configuration, git-commit

I don't have any global `user.email` or global `user.name` setup on purpose.

I like to set my user.email and user.name per repo by using the `git config user.email` and `git config user.name` commands.

On macOS with git version 2.17.0, if I forget to set `user.email` or `user.name` for a repo on my Mac, when I run `git commit` I get this error:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'lone@mymac.(none)')
```

This is good because it reminds me that I need to set the `user.email` and `user.name` config for my repo.

But on my Debian system with git version 2.11.0, if I forget to set `user.email` or `user.name` for a repo, whe I run `git commit` it commits the change with `Lone Learner <lone@mydeb>` as the author. I am guessing that it auto-detects `user.name` from `/etc/passwd` and auto-detects `user.email` as `<user>@<host>`.

I would like to disable this auto-detection of `user.name` and `user.email` on Debian or any system Git is on. If I have not explicity set `user.name` or `user.email` I want Git to fail in the manner it fails as shown in the Mac example above or in some other way. Is there anyway to achieve this either using `~/.gitconfig` or some other way?

Comment: duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19821895/1256452, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292895/6309

Comment: @torek Thank you for sharing the duplicates. I did try to search for existing questions on this topic before posting this question but the search terms I was trying (example: git prevent auto detect user.email) did not help.

Comment: Well, duplicates aren't bad, and are sometimes (as in this case) even good. See meta-discussion here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled I wasn't sure if I should close this, much less which one(s) to pick as the dupe... :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Git 2.8, use:

```
git config --global user.useConfigOnly true
```

That will avoid the "autodetection" done on your Debian environment.
See more at "[How do I make git block commits if user email isn't set?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292895/6309)".