# How to add git hook to the remote repository?

Tags: git, github, githooks

I've created a pre-commite hook and it works on my local machine, but I don't know how can I share this hook with my collegs

I will be grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance Denis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Git hook scripts be managed along with the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427207/can-git-hook-scripts-be-managed-along-with-the-repository)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It’s important to note that client-side hooks are not copied when you
>   clone a repository.

On Server side, the 1st hook is [pre-receive](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks).

Not everything is possible in this one, depending on what you want to do before the commit, but that's the place to do stuff if you want to do it for everybody who use the repository.

Note: You have to have access to the git server to do that.

Edit:

For global settings, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8842663/3445619
But this solution requires a new `git init` to be done by everyone.

If you don't have access to the git server or want to apply code ruler/styler, I would recommend to ask your colleague to make a link from `.git/hooks/pre-commit` to a versioned file where you can edit your own `pre-commit` hook for everyone.
Or simply share your file with them, if it will never change. (But this will have to be done for every newcomers).

Comment: I'd like run [jscs](http://jscs.info/overview) before commit. Is it ok to use pre-commit hook in this case?

Comment: yes, pre-commit is exactly the place to execute code styler or code ruler. But using pre-receive assums you already made the commit, thus it is too late to apply jscs. I'll edit the answer for your case.

Comment: Do you have access to you git server configuration ?

Comment: Then follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293498/git-commit-hooks-global-settings/8842663#8842663 to apply your rules to new users.

For the current users, i would prefer a versionned *hook* directory in your reposity, then *symbolic link* from your collegues to this hook

Comment: git config --global init.templatedir '~/.git_template' it's not clear enough, can you explain it in more detail, thanks

Comment: The example use *git_template* as a new folder for the new hooks without changing the basic configuration of git. (So the new git repository will not use your new hooks). You can out any name you want here. The command itself will replace all default hooks to the ones in the folder. So if you change the pre-commit hook in this folder, then ask your team to do `git init` this will change the default hooks configuration to the *git_template* you defined. I hope it clear enough, let me know if not.

Comment: I manage to do it partly, I have a problem with separate projects, because those commands (git config --global init.templatedir '~/.git_template' or git config core.hooksPath /path/to/my/centralized/hooks) sets global variables, so they make impediments for each other

Comment: i'm at work right now. If i remember right, there is an environment variable that can be setted to avoid the change to be applied on all the repositories of the server. I will do some research and get back to you later.

Comment: I guess i solved it yourself since you marked the question as "solved" ? You should delete the post with your skype id or it might become nightmare for you if it gets public somewhere ;-)