# How to Install the latest git core on linux?

Tags: git, ubuntu, version-control, apt, debian-based

I'm tring to install the latest git on linux (debian/ubuntu)

I tried

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

It got me

```
git --version
git version 2.7.4
```

But according to this article: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37293198
a more recent version exists.

(https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/RelNotes)

Comment: Hava you add a PPA on your OS? you can read more about PPA by https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them.

Comment: I just did those command, and do get a git 2.13

Comment: why is this question downvoted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command set

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

indeed installs the latest git. However you might want to try the command

```
which git
```

and see if you're executing the old binary, or the newly installed one.
At least that was the issue in my case.