# Script to Stop Git Commits if //TODO comments Are Present in Changes

Tags: git

I am relatively new to using Git and I was wondering if there was a nifty way to prevent `git commit` from running if it detects any `//TODO` statements in the changes that you are attempting to commit.

IntelliJ used to detect this for me when I did SVN commits, but I would like to know the best way to accomplish this on the command line.

Comment: use a pre-commit git hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to write and install a [pre-commit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) hook which looks for `// TODO` in changes and returns a non-zero exit status if it finds that string.

Comment: So I would have to put the hook in the directory of every project I work on? Is there a way to have it run no matter where I call git on my desktop?

Comment: @thatidiotguy, You want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2293498/391161).