# How to configure git to push to my user account by default

Tags: git, github

I work with hundreds of github repos, and it's getting a little tedious to set remotes in every repository when I need to push for a PR. Is there a way to set the default account for all pushes.

For example, I've cloned a repo:

```
git clone git://example.com/work/repo1
```

When I push, I'd like the branch to go to:

```
git push fork branch-name
```

But I'd like `fork` to refer to `git://example.com/employee/repo1` based on some global setting, so that it would "just work" as I contributed to repo2, repoG, repo0x03773H, etx.

Comment: You should be able to configure / write a "global" git client hook to add the remote on checkout.  More details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293498/git-commit-hooks-global-settings?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: You can also write a bash script and execute that whenever you want