# Auto setting custom hooks while cloning git repository?

Tags: git, githooks

Once I cloned the Bitbucket repository, under .git/hooks I'm able to see the pre-commit hook, and I have tested the execution with my own conditions to execute before commit.
Now I want the same pre-commit hook script to be shared within the team, and let others also use the same hook at their local .git repo.

As we are unable to push the .git/hooks changes to the remote repo, how can the other person get the same hooks at his local .git/repo?

Is there any way by cloning the git repo, that it will automatically modify the config path setting like HooksPath = ..... or execute the symlink command internally after the clone operation completed?

How can we achieve auto setting the custom hooks while cloning the git repository?

Please help me.. to distribute the hook scripts within my team.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying a git post-commit hook to all current and future repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293498/applying-a-git-post-commit-hook-to-all-current-and-future-repos)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithooks%5D+set+hook+clone