# How to make sure fixup commits are not merged into master branch

Tags: git, rebase, squash, git-squash

I use `git commit --fixup` (or `--squash`) a lot, especially during code reviews. Obviously these commits should eventually disappear after a `git rebase --autosquash` but it worries me that I might forget to rebase and merge these commits into master.

How can I ensure that either I cannot merge these into certain branches, or at least that certain branches cannot be pushed with these commits in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could at least block any pushes containing `fixup!` with the `pre-push` hook below.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use constant Z40 => '0' x 40;

my($remote,$url) = @ARGV;

my $abort_push = 0;
while (<STDIN>) {
  # <local ref> SP <local sha1> SP <remote ref> SP <remote sha1> LF
  my($lref,$lsha,$rref,$rsha) = split;

  if ($lsha eq Z40) {} # ignore deletes
  else {
    my $commit_range =
      $rsha eq Z40
        ? $lsha            # new branch: check all commits
        : "$rsha..$lsha";  # existing: check new commits since $rsha
    my @cmd = (qw/ git rev-list --pretty=oneline --grep ^fixup! /, $commit_range);

    open my $fh, "-|", @cmd or die "$0: failed to start git rev-list: $!";
    my @fixup_commits;
    while (<$fh>) { push @fixup_commits, "  - $_" }
    close $fh;

    if (@fixup_commits) {
      my $s = @fixup_commits == 1 ? "" : "s";
      warn "Remove fixup$s from $lref:\n", @fixup_commits;
      $abort_push = 1;
    }
  }
}

die "Push aborted.\n" if $abort_push;
```

So for example with a history of

```sh
$ git lola
* 4a732d4 (HEAD -> feature/foo) fixup! fsdkfj
| * 478075c (master) w00t
| * 1d572d3 fixup! sdlkf
| * f9a55ee fixup! yo
|/  
* ea708b0 (origin/master) three
* d4276a2 two
* 6426569 hello
```

Attempting to push gives

```sh
$ git push origin master feature/foo
Remove fixups from refs/heads/master:
  - 1d572d32f963d6218ed3b92f69d58a8ec790d7ea fixup! sdlkf
  - f9a55ee14f28f9496e2aea1bc400ca65ae150f4b fixup! yo
Remove fixup from refs/heads/feature/foo:
  - 4a732d4601012246986037437ac0c0bab39dd0a9 fixup! fsdkfj
Push aborted.
error: failed to push some refs to [...]
```

Note that `git lola` is a non-standard but [highly useful alias](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html). Add the following to your global `.gitconfig`.

```
[alias]
        lol = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
        lola = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37293198/2414411) for how to configure a global hook path (for all repositories).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Github, you could use a Github Action. The advantage of this is that anyone working on the repo will also avoid pushing temporary commits to the master branch.

This one blocks fixup and squash commits:
https://github.com/13rac1/block-fixup-merge-action

Or you could create your own for further customization:

```
name: Prevent Temporary Commits

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "*"

jobs:
  prevent-temp-commits:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Prevent Temporary Commits
        run: |
          BASE_SHA=$(git merge-base origin/master HEAD)
          git log $BASE_SHA..HEAD | grep -ie '^    fixup\|^    wip' && exit 1 || echo "No temporary commits found"
```

The custom one will fail a check (but still let you merge!) if there are any fixup or wip commits in the log of your branch in your PR.

Notes:

- You can add `squash` or anything else to the `grep` to expand your definition of what a temporary commit is.
- The whitespace in the `grep` is necessary (commit messages are indented)
- `fetch-depth: 0` is necessary and works well for smaller (most) repositories. See https://github.com/actions/checkout?tab=readme-ov-file#Fetch-all-history-for-all-tags-and-branches