# Git push size in pre-receive of the master

Tags: git, git-svn, githooks

I am trying to restrict the size of the git push using a `pre-receive` hook. In the case of svn I can do it with a precommit hook by checking the size of the transaction file. I am not sure how to do this with git. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I think this question is duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147699/limiting-file-size-in-git-repository