# Check commit size before pushing to git remote

Tags: git, github, githooks

I have a bug in my editor (it's horrible) where on occasion big files get written to the working directory. I then do a `git push` without manually checking for these big new files and the git remote gets overloaded and eventually errors out.

Is there some check (maybe a git hook) that I can use to check if my repo is above a certain size in MBs?

Comment: Are the big files always saved in a certain folder? Do the file names have a consistent pattern such as an irregular extension?

Comment: `git push` never does anything with uncommitted files. You must be committing them locally somehow. Are you blindly using `git add .` or similar? That's a bad anti-pattern.

Comment: yes I am committing them and push them by committing all files that aren't .gitignore'd

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman Have you got an answer yet? This is relevant for Bitbucket repos which have a maximum size of 1GB.

Answer (score 5):

Git does not use the work-tree in any way when you run `git push`.  Specifically, what `git push` pushes are *commits*, along with whatever objects—mostly files whose content was frozen into the commit at commit-time—are required to make those commits complete.<sup>1</sup>

Note that `git commit` itself *also* does not use the work-tree: it commits whatever is in the *index* (also called the *staging-area* and sometimes the *cache*).  This is why you must `git add` your files before committing.  There are a few options to `git commit` that make it automatically copy work-tree files over top of the versions of those files in the index / staging-area; but the principle remains: `git commit` commits what's in the index, not what's in the work-tree.

Your best bet at a Git *hook* for detecting this issue is therefore a pre-commit hook, as described in [the githooks documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html):

> pre-commit
>
>   This hook is invoked by
>   [git commit(1)](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html)
>   , and can be bypassed with the
>   `--no-verify`
>   option. It takes no parameters, and is invoked before
>     obtaining the proposed commit log message and making a commit. Exiting
>     with a non-zero status from this script causes the
>   `git commit`
>   command
>     to abort before creating a commit.

(There is a bit more to the documentation; follow the links to see.)

Writing Git hooks is a bit tricky (especially server side hooks) but this one is not too bad:

```
#! /bin/sh
# pre-commit hook: check for large files
TMP=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $TMP" 0 1 2 3 15
MAX_FILE_SIZE=1048576 # 1 MB
status=0
git ls-files --stage > $TMP
while read mode hash stage path; do
    objsize=$(git cat-file -s $hash)
    if [ $objsize -gt $MAX_FILE_SIZE ]; then
        echo "file too big: '$path' as staged exceeds $MAX_FILE_SIZE bytes" 1>&2
        status=1
    fi
done < $TMP
exit $status
```

(untested).  You could instead opt for a pre-push hook, but that's later than appropriate.

---

<sup>1</sup>These Git objects are also compressed.  Whenever possible, they are very-compressed by using existing previous objects already present on the server.  So if you have a ten gigabyte text file, but you make one small change to it and commit, pushing that commit—even though it has a ten gigabyte file inside it—takes very little space since the so-called *thin pack* that Git sends winds up saying: *Hey, remember that ten gigabyte object you already have?  Take that one, remove a few bytes from the middle, and replace them with these other bytes.*

Answer (score 2):

If you know the big file name or pattern e.g. suffix you can just add it to [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) until you resolve problems with your editor.

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9126745/1602555) which describes a server-side update hook.

Comment: that's a great idea, you deserve an upvote for that, but if you can find a generic way to solve the problem for any unknown big files, that'd be best

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman Update the answer with a link to [this hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9126745/1602555).

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman it's obvious you can gitignore something based on name. But there is a problem that git add -A, an git status -s, doesn't tell you the size, and git commit -m "sfds" doesn't tell you size. And you only find out there was something massive, when pushing it.  This can happen when dealing with frameworks or frameworks used within frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an ongoing concern, you should get into the habit of running `git status` before doing `git commit`. You can review the list of files that will be committed to look for ones that don't belong.

Comment: There can be loads in a project. especially when dealing with frameworks such that you haven't written or imported each individual file. And git status It won't tell you the size

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, if you want the size of multiple commits:

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), "[`git for-each-ref --format= <>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/be537062afe8be38631ee7b09ef09d06f03ab1ca/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt#L47)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---formatltformatgt))</sup>" learned `%(contents:size)`.

See [commit b6839fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6839fda6809b1de8d528837dfc99d0837f77c9d) (16 Jul 2020), and [commit 6e2ef8e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e2ef8eb06456e288a0a3cc451134479173cebc5), [commit 9fcc9ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9fcc9caf368aa1fb9ecc68c64b8918d82a637cdb) (10 Jul 2020) by [Christian Couder (`chriscool`)](https://github.com/chriscool).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit be53706](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be537062afe8be38631ee7b09ef09d06f03ab1ca), 30 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6839fda6809b1de8d528837dfc99d0837f77c9d): add support for `%(contents:size)`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Christian Couder</sup>

> It's useful and efficient to be able to get the size of the contents directly without having to pipe through `wc -c`.
>
> Also the result of the following:
>
> ```
> git for-each-ref --format='%(contents)' refs/heads/my-branch | wc -c
> ```
>
> is off by one as [`git for-each-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b6839fda6809b1de8d528837dfc99d0837f77c9d/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref))</sup> appends a newline character after the contents, which can be seen by comparing its output with the output from [`git cat-file`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b6839fda6809b1de8d528837dfc99d0837f77c9d/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file))</sup>.
>
> As with `%(contents)`, `%(contents:size)` is silently ignored, if a ref points to something other than a commit or a tag:
>
> ```
> $ git update-ref refs/mytrees/first HEAD^{tree}
> $ git for-each-ref --format='%(contents)' refs/mytrees/first
>
> $ git for-each-ref --format='%(contents:size)' refs/mytrees/first
> ```

`git for-each-ref` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b6839fda6809b1de8d528837dfc99d0837f77c9d/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt#L238):

> ### `contents:size`
>
> The size in bytes of the commit or tag message.