# Difference between pre-push and pre-receive hook in git?

Tags: git, githooks

Is there a difference between pre-push and pre-receive hook in git, in terms of use case or working logic?
The only difference I could understand from their [documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/githooks.txt#L211) was in terms of the input they receive -

1.**Pre-Push** : Information about what is to be pushed is provided on the hook's standard input with lines of the form - **local ref SP local sha1 SP remote ref SP remote sha1 LF**

2.**Pre-receive** : For each ref to be updated it receives on standard input a line of the format -
**old-value SP new-value SP ref-name LF**
However, I would like to know if there are particular use cases for each hook or can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One (`pre-push`) is a [**client-side** hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks), the other (`pre-receive`) is a [**server-side** hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks).

In that aspect, they are *very* different, and if you want to enforce *consistently* a given policy, you often do it in a pre-receive (server side) hook. That way, you don't have to worry about *deploying* a pre-push hook on each client.

Remember: hooks are **[*local* to a repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3703207/6309)**, which means a pre-push hook cannot easily be distributed to any **[downstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)**. But if those downstream repos are all referring to the same upstream repo, a pre-receive hook can apply to them all.

Comment: Okay. Then pre-push is a client side hook and pre-receive a server side hook, I believe?

Comment: @user1783805 I have added the notion of downstream repo: it is important.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Clear and concise answer!!

Comment: @user1783805 I have also addressed your question on a similar topic "[Create global pre-commit hooks for entire team](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25062860/6309)"

Comment: Should i use `pre-push` or `pre-receive` for some linting tests (like flake8) where i don't want to use `pre-commit` hooks? I want whole team to enforce the tests, a bit confused about it. Thank you.

Comment: " I want whole team to enforce the tests": then it is a pre-receive (server-side) hook, which will reject the push if the linter fails.