# Is possible to restrict "git" commands only in the root of the project?

Tags: git, husky

Is there a `git` setting to avoid other devs to commit from a subfolder? I want to set this to always run husky commands when a commit is made

- Allow: `project/`
- Dont allow: `project/subfolder/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such git setting.

You can customise your workflow by using git hooks. (client side hook like pre-commit-hooks or with server side hooks)

Comment: But git hooks are not propagated to the client when the repo is `clone`d, so he'll still need some way to install the (presumably pre-commit) hook in the repos of all the devs.  See discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25062860/12859753)

Comment: You can use server side hooks to validate the pull request.

Comment: Probably serverside hooks will do the trick, thanks