# Local `commit-msg` doesn't work in conjunction with global `prepare-commit-msg`

Tags: bash, git, shell, githooks

When I have my global git hooks directory (which contains just a `prepare-commit-msg` hook) set up in config, my local `commit-msg` doesn't run (although the global hook does). However, when I disable the global `prepare-commit-msg` hook (by commenting out `core.hookspath` in `gitconfig`), the local `commit-msg` hook works just fine.

`~/dotfiles/git-hooks/prepare-commit-msg`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pcregrep -Mv '(# Please.*|# with.*|^#$\n(?!#)|^#$(?=\n# On))' $1 > /tmp/msg && cat /tmp/msg > $1
```

`./.git/hooks/commit-msg` ([Gerrit's hook to add change-id's if necessary](http://review.example.com/tools/hooks/commit-msg), trimmed to remove license comments)

```
#!/bin/sh

...

unset GREP_OPTIONS

CHANGE_ID_AFTER="Bug|Depends-On|Issue|Test|Feature|Fixes|Fixed"
MSG="$1"

# Check for, and add if missing, a unique Change-Id
#
add_ChangeId() {
    clean_message=`sed -e '
        /^diff --git .*/{
            s///
            q
        }
        /^Signed-off-by:/d
        /^#/d
    ' "$MSG" | git stripspace`
    if test -z "$clean_message"
    then
        return
    fi

    # Do not add Change-Id to temp commits
    if echo "$clean_message" | head -1 | grep -q '^\(fixup\|squash\)!'
    then
        return
    fi

    if test "false" = "`git config --bool --get gerrit.createChangeId`"
    then
        return
    fi

    # Does Change-Id: already exist? if so, exit (no change).
    if grep -i '^Change-Id:' "$MSG" >/dev/null
    then
        return
    fi

    id=`_gen_ChangeId`
    T="$MSG.tmp.$$"
    AWK=awk
    if [ -x /usr/xpg4/bin/awk ]; then
        # Solaris AWK is just too broken
        AWK=/usr/xpg4/bin/awk
    fi

    # Get core.commentChar from git config or use default symbol
    commentChar=`git config --get core.commentChar`
    commentChar=${commentChar:-#}

    # How this works:
    # - parse the commit message as (textLine+ blankLine*)*
    # - assume textLine+ to be a footer until proven otherwise
    # - exception: the first block is not footer (as it is the title)
    # - read textLine+ into a variable
    # - then count blankLines
    # - once the next textLine appears, print textLine+ blankLine* as these
    #   aren't footer
    # - in END, the last textLine+ block is available for footer parsing
    $AWK '
    BEGIN {
        if (match(ENVIRON["OS"], "Windows")) {
            RS="\r?\n" # Required on recent Cygwin
        }
        # while we start with the assumption that textLine+
        # is a footer, the first block is not.
        isFooter = 0
        footerComment = 0
        blankLines = 0
    }

    # Skip lines starting with commentChar without any spaces before it.
    /^'"$commentChar"'/ { next }

    # Skip the line starting with the diff command and everything after it,
    # up to the end of the file, assuming it is only patch data.
    # If more than one line before the diff was empty, strip all but one.
    /^diff --git / {
        blankLines = 0
        while (getline) { }
        next
    }

    # Count blank lines outside footer comments
    /^$/ && (footerComment == 0) {
        blankLines++
        next
    }

    # Catch footer comment
    /^\[[a-zA-Z0-9-]+:/ && (isFooter == 1) {
        footerComment = 1
    }

    /]$/ && (footerComment == 1) {
        footerComment = 2
    }

    # We have a non-blank line after blank lines. Handle this.
    (blankLines > 0) {
        print lines
        for (i = 0; i < blankLines; i++) {
            print ""
        }

        lines = ""
        blankLines = 0
        isFooter = 1
        footerComment = 0
    }

    # Detect that the current block is not the footer
    (footerComment == 0) && (!/^\[?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+:/ || /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+:\/\//) {
        isFooter = 0
    }

    {
        # We need this information about the current last comment line
        if (footerComment == 2) {
            footerComment = 0
        }
        if (lines != "") {
            lines = lines "\n";
        }
        lines = lines $0
    }

    # Footer handling:
    # If the last block is considered a footer, splice in the Change-Id at the
    # right place.
    # Look for the right place to inject Change-Id by considering
    # CHANGE_ID_AFTER. Keys listed in it (case insensitive) come first,
    # then Change-Id, then everything else (eg. Signed-off-by:).
    #
    # Otherwise just print the last block, a new line and the Change-Id as a
    # block of its own.
    END {
        unprinted = 1
        if (isFooter == 0) {
            print lines "\n"
            lines = ""
        }
        changeIdAfter = "^(" tolower("'"$CHANGE_ID_AFTER"'") "):"
        numlines = split(lines, footer, "\n")
        for (line = 1; line <= numlines; line++) {
            if (unprinted && match(tolower(footer[line]), changeIdAfter) != 1) {
                unprinted = 0
                print "Change-Id: I'"$id"'"
            }
            print footer[line]
        }
        if (unprinted) {
            print "Change-Id: I'"$id"'"
        }
    }' "$MSG" > "$T" && mv "$T" "$MSG" || rm -f "$T"
}
_gen_ChangeIdInput() {
    echo "tree `git write-tree`"
    if parent=`git rev-parse "HEAD^0" 2>/dev/null`
    then
        echo "parent $parent"
    fi
    echo "author `git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT`"
    echo "committer `git var GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT`"
    echo
    printf '%s' "$clean_message"
}
_gen_ChangeId() {
    _gen_ChangeIdInput |
    git hash-object -t commit --stdin
}


add_ChangeId
```

`~/dotfiles/gitconfig` (trimmed) when global hook is enabled.

```
...

[core]
    editor = code -rwg $1:2
    excludesfile = /Users/shreyasminocha/.gitignore
    compression = 0
    hookspath = /Users/shreyasminocha/dotfiles/git-hooks

...
```

Git version: 2.18.0

Edit: As @phd pointed out in the comments, "The problem is that global hookspath completely takes over local hooks. If the global hookspath is defined local hooks are never consulted. [I had] to create global /Users/shreyasminocha/dotfiles/git-hooks/commit-msg that [would] run local .git/hooks/commit-msg". Confirming duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git global hooks and project hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178382/git-global-hooks-and-project-hooks)

Comment: @phd is that answer applicable even when the hooks are different?

Comment: The problem is that global `hookspath` completely takes over local hooks.  If the global `hookspath` is defined local hooks are never consulted. You have to create global `/Users/shreyasminocha/dotfiles/git-hooks/commit-msg` that will run local `.git/hooks/commit-msg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved this by adding some code to the global hook, just as @phd suggested. It looks for a local hook and runs it if it exists.

Global `prepare-commit-msg` hook:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# if a local hook exists, run it
if [ -e ./.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg ]; then
    ./.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg "$@"
fi

if [ -e ./.git/hooks/commit-msg ]; then
    ./.git/hooks/commit-msg "$@"
fi

# global_hook-related things follow
pcregrep -Mv '(# Please.*|# with.*|^#$\n(?!#)|^#$(?=\n# On))' $1 > /tmp/msg && cat /tmp/msg > $1
```