# Does Git Kraken support global git hooks

Tags: git, gitkraken

The Git Kraken documentation is not clear about support for global git hooks - only project git hooks.

I tried running global git hooks through Git Kraken and I can't seem to get it to work. I don't know if this is because Git Kraken doesn't support them or if I'm doing something wrong.

I have set the `hooksPath` git config variable to the directory of my global git hooks. They work when I commit through the terminal but not through Git Kraken.

Has anyone managed to get global git hooks to work with Git Kraken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that does not seem supported for now.

I mentioned [`core.hooksPath` in Git 2.9 in May 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37293001/6309), but GitKraken seems to look for hooks exclusively in `aproject/.git/hooks`.